# SP2013: Script editor web part not load

Tags: javascript

I am modified a document library view and try to increase width of one column. I added a script editor web part and added following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("TH.ms-vh2:contains('Title')").css("min-width", "250px"); 
});
</script>
```

It works fine at first load. But when I click Quick Edit view, the "title" column width is no longer 250px. When I click back to normal view, the "title" column width is not 250px, too. I think my javascript only load at first time I called the page.

How can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated to your specific problem, but have you checked out JSLink / CSR in SP2013 ? It's a better way to customize components at runtime with JS.

Comment: Cameron, I briefly take a look and it seems not easy to catch up compare to Script editor web part. But I will definitely look into JSlink later.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a content editor web part with a text file for a content source, then put a style tag in there and not use JavaScript at all...

```
<style>
    TH.ms-vh2:contains('Title') {
        min-width:250px;    
    }
</style>
```

You could also do this by editing the HTML Source directly in the content editor, but I find SharePoint thinks it knows how to enter my markup better than I do, and is quite frequently wrong...

If you still want to use JavaScript, I would still use a content editor with a text file for a content source, I just think script editors are a little fiddly to work with though...